# Custom Icons on fortysecondcv

Tags: graphics, cv, fontawesome

I am trying to build a CV, with the [fortysecondcv](https://da.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk) (right now it is taken way more than 40 seconds though).

When adding items to the sidebar, it uses the fontawesome package and a syntax like this, and produces

```
\social{\faLinkedin}
       {https://www.linkedin.com/in/steffenhvid/}
       {Linked In}
```

[image]

So looked up the function in the fortysecondcv.cls, and found

```
\newcommand*{\social}[3]{\socialicon{#1} & \href{#2}{#3}\\%
\newcommand*{\socialicon}[1]{\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\textcolor{iconcolor}{#1}}%
```

Then i tried, instead of adding a icon front fontawesome an icon from my local machine

```
\social{\includegraphics{D:/Dokumenter/CV/CV August 2019/pics/icons/linkedin.png}}
            {https://www.linkedin.com/in/steffenhvid/}
            {Linked In}
```

But it produces this:

[image]

I know its hard to see, but the small text infront of the icon is the path of the icon. I can't figure out what's going on, anyone got some input?

Comment: That's strange - does it also happen when you include the icon without a path, i.e., put the image file in the same folder as your `.tex` file and use `\includegraphics{linkedin.png}`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have two possibilites:

1. You can use the symbol `\faLinkedinSquare` to get the in inside a square like:

   ```
   \social{\faLinkedinSquare} % 
     {https://www.linkedin.com/in/steffenhvid/}
     {Linked In}
   ```

   with the result: 
   [image: faLinkedinSquare] or
2. you can define a new command `\icon` like this

   ```
   \newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=cvblue,cvblue,text=cvsidecolor] (char) {#1};}}
   ```

   and use it like this:

   ```
   \social{\icon{\faLinkedin}} % \faLinkedinSquare
     {https://www.linkedin.com/in/steffenhvid/}
     {Linked In}
   ```

   with the result:
   [image: faLinkedIn]

BTW: I would prefer the first possibility.

BTW2: If you add an MWE (short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue) to your question I can expand my answer and show how to use the given code above in your MWE ...

Comment: I do not want to use icons from from the fontawesome package. So none of the suggestions is usable. I am not sure their will be a MWE, since it loads from a custom class. I suppose i could include the entire class file, but it is allready present in the first link of the post.

Comment: @SteffenHvid Why do you want to use not fontawesome? Do you have an issue with that package? Then please name it in your question. Symbol       `\faLinkedinSquare` is perfectly the official used symbol of Linked In ...

Comment: i want the flexibility to use custom icons, as i need to include the python logo in another part of the resume, it just gives it more flexibility. I will try to create a MWE that reproduces the error.

Comment: after fiddling around i got it to work, i wish there was something clever i had changed but i did it exactly as in the example (trying to recreate the issue) and now it works. Thanks for you patience

Comment: @SteffenHvid If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).